# No Wireless and Bleutooth Interface in Ubuntu 16.04 with HP Notebook with Realtek chip

Tags: 16.04, wireless, bluetooth, hp, realtek-wireless

I have problem Bluetooth and with the wireless interface in dual boot with Windows 10 but only in Ubuntu. I have the HP Notebook 15-bw017nv the output of `sudo lshw -C network` is: 
`*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: 48:ba:4e:1d:c9:14
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:35 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d3304000-d3304fff memory:d3300000-d3303fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d2000000-d200ffff`
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: So the `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` gives:
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 DeviceName:  
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
05:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900] (rev ff)`
and `rfkill list all` gives:
`0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`